# Vertical Centering - How to keep an inline element in the middle of a block-level element vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a `<div>` that is containing a sentence. The height of `<div>` is based of `%` *(its height is changeable - depends on size of screen)*. Now I want to keep that sentence in the center (vertically) of `<div>`, How can I do that?

Here is a sample of what I said:

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>This should be center vertically</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css) and a host of other answers to this question which seems to get asked every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite technique is to add an `::after` pseudo-element to the parent element, wrap all the element's children in a single element, and let that element and the `::after` pseudo-element play the inline-block, vertical-alignment game:

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}
div span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This should be centered vertically, and now it is!</span></div>
```

The `::after` pseudo-element having `height: 100%` will expand dynamically with the height of the parent, thus the inner element will always be centered vertically.

Comment: What happens if I use `::before` instead of `::after`? I tested it, I did not get any difference ..

Comment: Nope, there should be no difference in this context since the `::after` is supposed to be hidden anyway.  The only difference between `::before` and `::after` is DOM order (which affects natural stacking, etc...).  But in this case, since the pseudo-element will be invisible, we don't care about that.  Either one will work.

Answer (score 4):

Use [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>This should be center vertically</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, my friend.  I love flexbox.  Take pity on us who have to support IE 9...

Comment: @bowheart Oh yeah that's sad. I think the answer below can help you if you are able to edit your html, e.g. adding `<span></span>`

Answer (score 1):

Seen two methods already. Here is another method using table and table-cell. give `display: table`to parent and `table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to the child and see the magic.

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 250px;
  display: table;
  height: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}
div span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This should be centered vertically</span></div>
```